# Application java version migration/upgrading best approach

Tags: java, migration, upgrade, java-11

I am managing a web application which interacts/depends on some REST services which further depends on other services. Majority of these services are on java 8 and just a few on java 6. I plan to upgrade all of them to java 11. Thinking of phase-by-phase approach to upgrade some services, test them and then roll out them to prod. Then do the same for next selected set of services till all are on java 11.

How to go about it? Top down approach or bottom-up? i.e first should I start upgrading "Main application" roll to prod, then "Rest Service 1", "Rest Service 2", "Rest Service 3". Followed by "Rest Service 1.1", "Rest Service 1.2"..etc or should it be from bottom starting from "Rest Service 1.1.1.1". Or sequence doesn't matter because they are different services all together. What is best approach here or any good practices to keep in mind.

[image]

Comment: Questions about good practices are generally off-topic on SO since they draw opinions. Mine -  I would preferably choose moving *top-down*. Considering a few things - 1. It doesn't matter for REST services on which version of Java they're running. 2. (Assumption) The topmost component would be more tightly coupled with your individual application, yet going down the services might be responsible to serve other applications as well. So, in general, depends on a few other design decisions such as risking `Rest Service 1` as compared to `Rest Service 1.1.1.1` is how critical to your systems.

Comment: Or if all such concerns result in neutral effect, I would suggest *bottom-up* in a sense that chooses the service with least external dependencies first and then moves to bigger chunks.

Comment: Explain your diagram. Is it "uses" dependency, "compile" dependency or something else?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the REST APIs don't change (and they shouldn't), it doesn't really matter which Java version they are running on, so don't worry about approaching one way or another. Just take any service, upgrade, fix any issues (there shouldn't be a lot) and deploy it to prod.

[This article](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/) explains some possible compatibility problems you may face.